# have resulted in people injured, cars ruined, and horses dead or hurt

Tags: being

In an American news story titled "[Judge Orders NYPD Turn Over Public Records On Horse-Drawn Carriage Incidents](http://newyork.cbslocal.com/2014/04/28/group-demands-nypd-turn-over-public-records-on-horse-drawn-carriage-incidents/)", there's this passage:

> On Monday, carriage opponents said the judge’s ruling is sure to shed light on many more incidents.
>
> “It’s in everybody’s best interests to see what’s actually happened; to see the records of how many accidents that **have resulted in people injured, cars ruined, and horses dead or hurt**,” said Dan Mathews, senior vice president of People for the Ethical Treatment of Animals.

Is the boldfaced portion of the quotation of Dan Mathews grammatically fine as is, if it is to be used in a formal writing?

Also, is the original closer in meaning to which of the following?

> (1) ...have resulted in people *being* injured, cars *being* ruined, and horses *being* dead or hurt
>
> (2) ...have resulted in people *who are* injured, cars *that are* ruined, and horses *that are* dead or hurt

### EDIT

After reviewing the answers, an edit seems to be in order. Let me rephrase the original sentence as follows:

> ...accidents that **have resulted in people injured**," said Dan Mathews...

Now, instead of having three items coordinated, we have only one: "people injured". Is this still grammatical without "being" between "people" and "injured"?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the original.

Comment: That I've already learned from the two answers. How about the edited sentence with only "people injured"? Isn't "being" required here as in "people being injured"?

Comment: The real problem is with _how many accidents that have resulted in..._. Should be _how many accidents have resulted in..._ or just _how many accidents resulted in..._.

Answer (score 1):

The portion in bold is grammatically correct. Your option #1 most closely matches the meaning.

The construction in the cited piece simply uses post-positioned adjectives, for dramatic effect. It is identical to saying ". . . injured people, ruined cars, and dead or hurt horses".

But I take issue with the grammar preceding  the bolded part of the cited text, which uses a "**how many. . . that** construction.

- **how** many accidents **that** have. . .

This should be either

- **the** many accidents **that have**. . .

Or

- **how** many accidents **have**. . . 
  (less preferred, because it goes less well after "records of"— it would go better after "records showing")

Answer (score -1):

Your (1) or an alternate expression using an ing-form is the canonical way. See at Google Books:

["have resulted in people"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22accidents%20that%20have%20resulted%20in%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22have%20resulted%20in%20people%22)

and look at their continuations.

However, now and then one finds the original. I consider

"have resulted in people injured"

closer to

"have resulted in people **having been** injured"

than to your alternatives.

Comment: I'm interested in what types of verb forms are allowed after "people". When I searched "(have) resulted in people being injured" in Google Books, I had some instances. But I got no instance in Google Books of either "(have) resulted in people injured" or "(have) resulted in people having been injured".

Comment: Leave out *injured* and you will see the formation with [various verbal phrases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+resulted+in+people&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20resulted%20in%20people%3B%2Cc0). Google Books allows a maximum *five-word* search